# Make variable folder in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently I have a button in a form in access that runs a VBA. This VBA makes a folder and then exports a file from access db into an excel file in that folder.
The code is this:

```
MkDir CurrentProject.Path & "\W46"
Dim outputlot3mah As String
outputlot3mah = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "W46" & "\" & "Lot03_MAHs.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Lot03_MAHs", outputlot3mah, True
```

Is there a way that when the user clicks the button, he can enter a name and that will be the name of the folder? So for example if he chooses W78 as the name, the folder is named W78 and the file is entered in that folder.

So then it would be something like this

```
Dim getFolderName As String
MkDir CurrentProject.Path & getFolderName
Dim outputlot3mah As String
outputlot3mah = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & getFolderName & "\" & "Lot03_MAHs.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Lot03_MAHs", outputlot3mah, True
```

I'm new to VBA so I don't know if this is possible.
Thank you!

Comment: You can display an `InputBox` for the user to type the folder name. Have a default folder name in case no value was inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use inputbox to get a string from user.

something like this

```
Dim getFolderName As String

getFolderName = InputBox("Give me the name of the folder")

MkDir CurrentProject.Path & getFolderName
Dim outputlot3mah As String
outputlot3mah = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & getFolderName & "\" & "Lot03_MAHs.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Lot03_MAHs", outputlot3mah, True
```

you have also to have some error control:

- verify if user hit cancel
- check if the folder exists
- create the folder if it doenst exist